# How to parse HTML <div> tag from scratch without using any library in java

Tags: java, html, string

I want to parse particular `div` tag's all inner elements in java

**For Example**:
Consider a given HTML code are String. If I parse `<div id="6">` in below code it will be get all inner tags include sub div tags.
How can I write code without using any library. Using only String methods.

```html
<div id="1">
    <div id ="2">
        <span id="3">
        </span>
        <div id="4">
            <div id="5">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="6">
        <img id="7" />
        <input id="8" />
        <br id="9" />
        <span id="10">
            <div id="11">
                <div id="12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <div id="13">
            <pre id="14">
            </pre>
        </div>
        <span id= "15">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pls share your ideas and any resources for reference.